# Replacing faulty window motor from another VAG car

Tags: electrical, vw, part-identification, parts, seat

I own Seat Ibiza 1.4 petrol, and front passengers window motor is not working and I have to replace it. The part number is **6R0959802EE**. I want to buy a used part instead of a new one to save some money, but the problem is that I can't find it with this number. I can find lots of these but without *EE* at the end (**6R0959802**) and this part belong to VW Polo.

So my question is if I put **6R0959802** (from Polo) instead of **6R0959802EE** (originally on Seat) will the window motor still work?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Lots of the parts should match up between the Polo and Ibiza if of the same years (or near to it ... same generation). The thing you need to be aware of is most vehicles have different parts for front/rear as well as left/right. I'm not sure about the Ibiza, but would bet as long as it is the front pass side of the Polo, you should be in good shape ... just my intuition, as I don't know for sure.

Comment: Good luck ; I had a bad window motor in an Olds and found in the shop manual it was welded into the door and needed to be cut out. So I lived with an intermittent motor.

Comment: @blacksmith37 had to check a window motor and when I got it out, not only was bearing backlash adjustable but so were the brushes... But you get what you pay for: this was on a Rolls-Royce !